# How to access the controls in the TabPage of a TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two Buttons in my Form and two TextBoxes inside a TabControl.

I'm not sure how I can save to the Clipboard the text of the TextBoxes using the Buttons.
To do this, we tried to assigned the same `AccessibleName` to the controls.

I worked on the code but I do not know how to access the TabPages of the TabControl.
Finally, does someone know of a better way to do that?

[image: See Screen Shot of my Form]

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private void SaveNumBot(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
        {
            if (c.AccessibleName == ((Control)sender).AccessibleName)
            {
                if (c is TextBox)
                {
                    Clipboard.SetDataObject(c.Text);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify your foreach loop:

```
foreach(TabPage tabPage in yourTabControl.Controls)
{
    foreach (TextBox textBox in tabPage.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(x=>x.AccessibleName == ((Control)sender).AccessibleName))
    {
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(textBox.Text);
    }
}
```

with this loop you only search for `Controls` which are from the type `Textbox`.
Use `OfType` method to avoid `InvalidCastExceptions`. 
If you have other Controls which inherit from `TextBox` in your Form I would recommend to add the line `x.GetType()==typeof(TextBox)` to the `Where()` method.
With the `Where()` method we only choose the items which have to same `AccessibleName` like our `sender`.

But if you have more `textboxes` with the same `AccessibleName`, this loop will run through all items and only choose the last text.

In this case i would recommend:

```
Clipboard.SetDataObject(yourTabPage.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()
                        .Where(x=>x.AccessibleName ==((Control)sender).AccessibleName))
                        .ToList()
                        .FirstOrDefault().Text);
```

Here we are going to have 1 text from the first texbox found in the Control. you could also select the `Last()`entry.

Comment: that last example: my eyes!

Comment: @DanielA.White i have only suggested options

Comment: Thanks for the good code
 I learned a lot
But this.Controls refers to my form
And my controllers are on a tabcontrol and my main problem is that I do not know how to look for controllers inside tabcontrol

Comment: @shahab47 in this case you have to run through the `yourTabPage.Controls` instead of `this.Controls`

Comment: @ Mario Mitterbauer And if I have a few tabs, how should I search?
Sorry it was complicated :(
But the main thing in the image I have is the fever

Comment: @shahab47 for this you have to run through all tabpages `foreach(TabPage tabPage in yourTabControl.Controls)`

Comment: @MarioMitterbauer And I thank you again
Solved my friend :) THANKS

Answer (score 1):

Use pattern matching:

```
if (c is TextBox textBox)
{
    Clipboard.SetDataObject(textBox.Text);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work
Because all the buttons and textboxes are on a tabcontrol
I put a picture of my form if you see I'm grateful